# Difference of two simple roots is zero (?)

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

I am studying simple Lie algebras and, on page 129 of the book "Group Theory A physicist's Survey", by Pierre Ramond, it is claimed at the bottom of the page that << Hence the difference of two simple roots must be zero >>.

To arrive at this statement the author recalls that for positive roots to be simple as well << (...) none can be expressed as linear combination of other simple roots with positive coeficients.>> These simple roots are introduced under the notation: $\alpha_i, i =1, 2, ..., r$ where r is the rank of the algebra.

MY QUESTION follows from the equalities at the end of the same page that should allow to conclude that the difference between two simple roots is zero.

Using the difference between two simple roots, $\alpha_{\Delta} = \alpha_i - \alpha_j$, to write $\alpha_i$ as

$\alpha_i = \alpha_{\Delta} + \alpha_j$

I can only immediately conclue that $\alpha_{\Delta}$ is not another simple root otherwise it would violate the given definition. But how can I conlude that it must be zero? If such statment is true, the previous equation becomes $\alpha_i = \alpha_j$ which is not looking good.

print of the page for more details: [image: page_129]
print of the next page : [image: next_page]

Comment: This question in the present form is unanswerable. Most likely, the author proves equality of two simple roots satisfying some further properties. You should not expect the reader of your question to have access to to book you are reading (personally, I never heard of it).

Comment: Ok, maybe I should add a print of this part of the book?

Comment: As written in that source, that's kind of nonsense. What the author should be showing there, and what the argument kind of shows, is that the difference of two simple roots is *not a root at all*. Of course it's never zero as soon as those two simple roots are distinct.

Comment: ok, thanks for the review! This was anoying me for a while but so it turns out that the author concluded something wrong here while trying to show what you just said... Which I agree and can understand. Thanks!

Comment: Then the author goofed. In the last paragraph it should be written: The difference of two simple roots cannot be a simple root. What does he say in the next paragraph?

Comment: On the next page the author talks about the only three possible angles between simple roots in a chain. Should I add a print as well ?

Comment: If you do, one can try to figure out what the author had in mind.

Comment: ok I will add it right now